# c# window form Search Data guide

Tags: c#-4.0

I have written my code to search a record matching the primary key from sql Database, now I want to show a message box  "id is not exist" if there is no matching record for the entered id in idtextbox. My code is this:

```
try
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MUDASSAR-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=HMS;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

    ds.Clear();
    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Doctor where Id=@Id", con);

    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = IdtextBox.Text;

    da.Fill(ds);

    dataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error:" + ex);
}
```

Comment: Did you take a look around the internet?.

Answer (score 0):

`Fill` returns number of rows effected. You can use this.

```
int count = da.Fill(ds)
if(count == 0)
{
    //Show your message here
}
```